# Correct usage of ReadOnlySequence<T> on implementing ReadOnlySequenceSegment<T>

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.1

I'm trying to implement a network library to complete my from scratch library [**Astron**](https://github.com/thenameless314159/Astron) since a few days and I have a few questions. In order to handle Nagle correctly, I must have a frame parsing logic. So while doing that using the new pipeline API I noticed that output was provided as a read-only sequence, therefore I had to make a custom SequenceReader but I'm having some problems while testing it. I think I've misunderstood the new `Span<T>` and `Memory<T>` API :/

1. Is it relevant to mock the sequence segment?

In order to test as many behaviors as possible, I had to implement the `ReadOnlySequenceSegment<T>` abstract class, which I did using the `Moq` library to know when the next segment has been getting, here it is :

```cs
    public class SequenceSegment : ReadOnlySequenceSegment<byte>
    {
        private readonly Mock<SequenceSegment> _mock;
        private ReadOnlySequenceSegment<byte> _next;

        public new ReadOnlySequenceSegment<byte> Next
        {
            get
            {
                var mockNext = _mock.Object.Next; // simulate get from the mock
                return _next;
            }
            protected set => _next = value;
        }

        public SequenceSegment(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory)
        {
            Memory = memory;
            _mock = new Mock<SequenceSegment>(memory);
        }

        public SequenceSegment Add(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> mem)
        {
            var segment = new SequenceSegment(mem)
            {
                RunningIndex = RunningIndex + Memory.Length
            };
            Next = segment;
            return segment;
        }

        public void VerifyGetNext() => _mock.VerifyGet(ss => ss.Next);
    }
```

As you can see I had to override the Next property with the `new` keyword which is a bad practice but I assume while testing it's fine?

Here is the test that doesn't pass :

```cs
        [Fact]
        public void TryRead_ShouldReturnTrue_OnSegmentSplitted()
        {
            var buffer = _createBuffer(); // int + int = 8bytes buffer
            var firstSegment = new SequenceSegment(buffer.Slice(0, 3));
            var secondSegment = firstSegment.Add(buffer.Slice(3, 5));

            var input = new ReadOnlySequence<byte>(
                firstSegment, 0,
                secondSegment, 4);

            var reader = new SequenceReader(input);
            reader.TryRead(BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian, out var firstValue); // throw here
            reader.TryRead(BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian, out var secondValue);

            Assert.Equal(_firstValue, firstValue);
            Assert.Equal(_secondValue, secondValue);
            firstSegment.VerifyGetNext();
        }
```

Test output :

```
Message: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: start
```

I commented the line that throws the exception on the test, so I assume my sequence logic is okay? Let's see the code of my SequenceReader with the line that throws commented :

```cs
    public class SequenceReader
    {
        private const int _maxStackalloc = 128;
        protected ReadOnlySequence<byte> _input;

        public SequenceReader(ReadOnlySequence<byte> input) => _input = input;

        public delegate T ReadDelegate<out T>(ReadOnlySpan<byte> src);

        /// <summary>
        /// Try to read a <see cref="T"/> with the <see cref="ReadDelegate{T}"/> specified as an arg.
        /// The <see cref="SequenceReader"/> then advance the current position according to the size of <see cref="T"/>.
        /// <see cref="T"/> must be a struct :
        /// <see cref="byte"/>, <see cref="sbyte"/>, <see cref="bool"/>, <see cref="short"/>, 
        /// <see cref="ushort"/>, <see cref="int"/>, <see cref="uint"/>, <see cref="long"/>, 
        /// <see cref="ulong"/>, <see cref="float"/>, <see cref="double"/>, <see cref="decimal"/>, 
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type to read.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="read">The delegate to read the <see cref="T"/>. Must be a method from <see cref="BinaryPrimitives"/></param>
        /// <param name="result">The result returned.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns true if the read was successful, else returns false.</returns>
        public unsafe bool TryRead<T>(ReadDelegate<T> read, out T result) where T : unmanaged
        {
            result = default;
            var size = sizeof(T);
            if (size > _maxStackalloc) return false;
            if (size > _input.Length) return false;

            if (_input.First.Length >= size)
                result = read(_input.First.Span);
            else
            {
                Span<byte> local = stackalloc byte[size];
                _input.Slice(size).CopyTo(local); // throws at the slice
                result = read(local);
            }

            _input = _input.Slice(size);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I already tried to change the line to `_input.Slice(0, size)` but nothing changed, also not on this successful test :

```cs
        [Fact]
        public void TryRead_ShouldReturnTrue_OnSegmentComplete()
        {
            var input = new ReadOnlySequence<byte>(_createBuffer());

            var reader = new SequenceReader(input);
            reader.TryRead(BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian, out var firstValue);
            reader.TryRead(BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian, out var secondValue);

            Assert.Equal(_firstValue, firstValue);
            Assert.Equal(_secondValue, secondValue);
        }
```

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, please if you have any idea it'd be awesome if you can help me!

Comment: I think the key thing you're missing here is that you haven't set `base.Next` - I probably wouldn't have a separate field at all, nor would I use MOQ here - you can create your own concrete sequences relatively simply - example: https://github.com/mgravell/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/blob/fd71a6de7b355ac2364a21dff3aca0d1aeb70bf7/src/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/Arenas/SequenceSegment.cs#L132-L138

Comment: What a savior ! :O Yeah I think I've seen the point, i'm actually trying to test the BCL ? Which shouldn't be done. I'm missing many point unfortunately, because then my reader provide me wrong output : first read value correspond to the second value and the second value is 0 :/ I don't want to put this under the carpet so i'll try to make it works the way I want in order to understand a little bit more  all of this ^^ But I could, I'm using your unofficial release as well therefore I assume the splitted sequence from your lib would be indeed parsed with this test ^^

Comment: But splitted this way it works : `var firstSegment = new SequenceSegment(buffer.Slice(0, 4));`
            `var secondSegment = firstSegment.Add(buffer.Slice(4, 4));`